# RiverPod StateProvider returns before code runs in function

Tags: flutter, riverpod

These print statements don't get printed in order of how the appear. I tried to make this `async` but it blows up. Essentially I need to listen to a `StreamProvider` and update a `StateProvider` based on the stream. Here is my code for the `StateProvider`.

```
final unreadNotificationsProvider = StateProvider.autoDispose<bool>((ref) {
  final notifications = ref.watch(notificationsStreamProvider.stream);

  bool unreadNotificationsRead = false;

  notifications.listen((objects) {
    for (var n = 0; n < objects.length; n++) {
      print("objects: ${objects[n].notification.read}"); <-- Prints second
      if (!objects[n].notification.read) {
        print("GETTING HERE"); // <-- Prints third
        unreadNotificationsRead = true;
      }
    }
  });

  print("unreadNotificationsRead: $unreadNotificationsRead"); // <-- Prints first

  return unreadNotificationsRead;
});
```

Comment: Can you please produce the console error messages, and point what exactly you are facing in this code

Comment: I believe because the stream is an asyncrhonous operation it will run later even if you start listening first, I don't know what you try to accomplish but have you tried using FutureProvider or StreamProvidercwith async* / yield for the first value

Comment: Yes, this is working as designed.  if you want a value that is updated on each update to the stream, just use a stream provider directly.  don't insert a state provider in the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get the value of the stream instead of listening, you dont have to listen the stream because you are already usign ref.watch means the stateProvider will update everytime the notificationsStreamProvider changes.

Replace

```
final notifications = ref.watch(notificationsStreamProvider.stream);
```

For

```
final notifications = ref.watch(notificationsStreamProvider).asData?.value;
```

Remove `notifications.listen` and your `objects` variable will be `notifications` and before accesing you should ask if `notifications == null` or `notifications.isEmpty`

Let me know...